# Split column text to adjacent columns using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with a column containing texts like "Hello there 2005 A" I want to split this text in between two columns, one containing 'Hello there 2005' and the other saying 'A'.

I have tried Split function in VBA, but I can't make it loop through the entire column or even come up with a delimeter which will split exactly before the letter 'A'.

Results should look something like this:

[image: Results]

Comment: First you should determine the splitting rule. Is it always before the last letter? Is it the 3rd space? Is it the 17th character? Is it just this one string you want to split or are there others that should be split as well - with what common rule? If you cannot define a rule it will be impossible to automate.

Comment: It looks like a good rule would be everything after the number? Please confirm if that will work and then this can be easily accomplished.

Comment: Also, why are there blank rows in your sample results?

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes that is exactly what I want. I apologise for my oversight. Please ignore the blank rows.

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes I thought that splitting the text after the numbers would work. But I have been unsuccessful in doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim cell As Range
Dim strng As Variant
Dim rightStrng As String
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("multimanager") '<== change it as per your needs
    For Each cell In .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) 'assuming that "column containing texts" is column "A"
        strng = Split(cell)
        rightStrng = ""
        i = UBound(strng)
        Do While Not IsNumeric(strng(i)) And i > 0
            rightStrng = strng(i) & " " & rightStrng
            i = i - 1
        Loop
        If IsNumeric(strng(i)) Then
            rightStrng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(rightStrng)
            cell.Offset(, 2) = rightStrng
            cell.Offset(, 1) = Left(cell.Value, IIf(rightStrng <> "", InStrRev(cell.Value, rightStrng) - 2, Len(cell.Value)))
        End If
    Next cell

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @user3598756! This helps me so much. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)(cellValue," ")
will give you the position of your first space

```
firstPos = instr(cellValue," ")  ' first space
secondPos = instr(firstPos + 1, cellValue, " ") ' second space
```

etc..

or

followed by [mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx), and [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
secondColumnValue = mid(cellValue, thirdPos + 1)
firstColumnValue = replace(cellValue, secondColumnValue, "")
```