# Split columns based on matching data in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in which I am comparing the text for both of them. Column A contains text 'Hello 2005 A LW Allocate' and the column B has text 'A LW' .  I want to split the text in column A such that column C should have 'Hello 2005 Allocate' and D should have 'A LW'. The value in column B can be among a specific list of values {A, A LW, I , J} etc and I want to match the same text to that of column A and split it. I would really appreciate if someone can help. Right now, I have a code which looks something like this:

```
`Sub Testing()
  Dim DataRange As Range, CheckRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
   Dim rightStrng As String
   Dim i As Long
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
  Set CheckRange = ws.Range("C2,C35000") - Column which has data
  Set DataRange = ws.Range("F2,F34") - Column to which I am comparing data
   With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
   For Each aCell In CheckRange.Rows
    Set bCell = DataRange.Find(What:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set strng = Split(bCell)
Set rightStrng = ""
 i = UBound(strng)
rightStrng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(rightStrng)
 Set bCell.Offset(, 2) = rightStrng
Set bCell.Offset(, 1) = Left(aCell.Value, IIf(rightStrng <> "", InStrRev(bCell.Value, rightStrng) - 2, Len(bCell.Value)))
Next aCell
End Sub`
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038525/split-column-text-to-adjacent-columns-using-excel-vba)

Comment: @OldUgly I was trying to split it based on numbers in that question. In here, I am trying to split it based on comparison

Comment: Neither of your two questions meets the lowest threshold of what could be considered a quality question. While the first might be overlooked with the excuse that you simply didn't know where to start, you have two valid answers that could have been reshaped to cover the new criteria. This is a problem with providing 'turn-key' answers to crappy questions; the OP (you in this case) is led to believe that they have provided sufficient information and original effort and use the quality of their previous effort as a template for a new question. Read [ask] and [mcve] and improve this question.

Comment: `problem with providing 'turn-key' answers to crappy questions` so true yet people continue to do it XD

Comment: Can we see any attempts you've made?  This request feels like a case of Plz give meh teh codez

Comment: `Set strng = Split(bCell)` is bad.

Comment: @CodeJockey the code I have posted above is my attempt. I am a novice at this. And I am trying my best.Also, I am just trying to figure out things as I am learning.

Comment: @ShilpiT Now that you have some code posted, we should be able to help more.  We are not trying to be bullies.  We are tech people, so we can be sensitive to being bullied e.g. people who come on here and ask us to write code for them.

Comment: @CodeJockey I understand. I appreciate all the help I can get right now. I am trying to figure out where do I indicate to split when it finds its matching value in the second column

Comment: @ShilpiT I'm not convinced you REALLY want `Split` see answer below.  If you want to know more about Split, try here: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, this answer is still a little bit of this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZO1jauV31U

But I felt an honest effort was given, despite the similar, original post.

**Approach:**

It looks like you are trying to do some string parsing, returning the position of the spaces in your string and then using `Left` to return the left half `Mid` to return the middle, and `Right` to return the right part.  Instead, I might try iterating over your list of possible entries, if I find them, replace them with `vbNullString` and print what I found in Column B

**Instr([Start], [String1], [String2], [Compare]:**

The `Instr` function will return the position of `String2` found in `String1` or zero, if the string is not found.   `Start` is the position in the string to start from (usually 1 for the beginning).  `Compare` is the only true optional parameter, specifying how to compare the strings.

```
Debug.Print Instr(1, "abcd", "b") '<-- prints 2 in your immediate window
```

**Replace**

The `Replace(Expression, Find, Replace)` function will return the `Expression` string with instances of the `Find` string replaced with the `Replace` string.

```
Debug.Print Replace("abcdefg", "abc", "ABC") '<-- Prints "ABCdefg" in the immediate window.
```

**Your application**

Some pseudo code for you to consider:

```
Dim searchVals(3) as String
searchVals(0) = " A "
searchVals(1) = " A LW "
searchVals(2) = " I "
searchVals(3) = " J "    '<-- surrounded with spaces so we don't find all Js

'...some code you already wrote...
For Each myCell in myColumn
    For i = 0 to 3
    'For each search value I expect to find...
        'If this search value is in there...
        If InStr(1, myCell.Value, searchVals(i)) <> 0 Then
            'I found my string!  Replace the searchVal with a null string (i.e. remove it)
            myCell.Offset(,1) = Replace(myCell.Value, searchVals(i), vbNullString)
            'Print the string I found two to the Right
            myCell.Offset(,2) = searchVals(i)
            Exit For '<-- Once I find one, I can stop searching
        End If
    Next i
Next myCell
```

**Errors in your code**

I suspect you are getting an error message one this line:

```
Set strng = Split(bCell)
```

The `Set` keyword is reserved for objects in VBA and `Split` returns an array of strings.  So both these lines:

```
Set strng = Split(bCell)
Set rightStrng = ""
```

should be:

```
strng = Split(bCell)
rightStrng = ""
```

For newbies, this is typically something to memorize, but for more technical stuff on what the `Set` keyword does: [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much. I tweaked it to atch my exact needs. I don't know why I was stuck on the Split function. but this is so much better!! Thanks again